# Auto-resize a monospacedDigit font in IOS-9

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9, autoresize, monospace

In IOS-9, Apple introduced varying widths for digits in the system font. That looks great for digits/numbers that stand on their own, but gets very irritating for e.g. a count-down timer. Luckily Apple has thought of that, and introduced the `monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:` method on `UIFont` to get the System font with old-fashioned fixed width digits.

However, that does not seem to work together with auto-resizing.

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
field.minimumFontSize = 20;
field.font = [UIFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:44 weight:UIFontWeightSemibold];
field.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

If the text fits in the field, it works fine. When shrinking the field size, so that the text does not fit anymore, the font shrinks but switches to variable-width digits. Even after growing the field to its original size, so that the text fits again, the font still shows variable-width digits.

Has anybody gotten this to work properly?

**EDIT**: I have now opened a bug report for this with Apple: [rdar://24074201](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5012128889044992)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. This sounds like a good bug report!